# Is there a way to incorporate a PNG with stroke layers using Grease Pencil

Tags: objects, grease-pencil, layers

I am animating a hand holding a crayon. The hand is a 2-D grease pencil stroke layer with a full layer and the crayon is a PNG imported as a plane. I was able to animate the crayon to move around with the hand but my trouble comes with layering as I am not able to get the crayon to layer properly with the hand to look like it is holding it. I am having trouble finding any help with this through a Google search so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello ! A screenshot would help a lot visualizing the problem but if I understand correctly, you need to use a mask to manually hide the grease pencil when it should be hidden by the crayon.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ll try it out.